# Why is the get_absolute_url() defined in the models.py?

Tags: python, django, generics

I am trying to redo my app views with a Class Based Views(CBV) and stumbled across this function get_absolute_url() being defined in the models.py, [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormViewhttp://)

I have created models and have never used this function before. Is this specific to CBVs?

Comment: It's just an example for a method. Nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specific to CBV, you can use it anywhere in your application. It makes it much easier to get the url for a model instance without having to mess around with url resolving. Also it is much easier to get the definitive url for your object in a template when you can call `get_absolute_url` on the object itself. For example, if you are looping through a list of objects:

```
{% for post in blog_posts %}
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">read post</a>
{% endfor %}
```

That said, there's nothing stopping you using the method in your view either:

```
post = BlogPost.objects.get(...)
url = post.get_absolute_url()
```

There's also is nothing at all special about the method though. You can write your own `get_foo_url()` if you like instead. For example, I [wrote a blog post about a `get_admin_url`](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/reversing-admin-urls-and-creating-admin-links-you-models/), a method to allow you to get the Django admin url to an object:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_admin_url(self):
        content_type = ContentType \
            .objects \
            .get_for_model(self.__class__)
        return reverse("admin:%s_%s_change" % (
            content_type.app_label,
            content_type.model),
            args=(self.id,))

 # {{ book.get_admin_url }}
```